# UIView Animation not working properly in IOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewanimation

I have a method to animate and reset the view which is given below.

```
-(void)animateToFocus:(BOOL)animate index:(NSInteger)index {
    if (animate) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Scroll" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -50*index, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    } else {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Scroll" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

}
```

When I pass YES and a tag in this method, it will animate to top and when I pass NO it will reset the view.
It works perfectly in IOS6.When i update to IOS 7,  resetting done as:[image]

It will not animate completeley and a black space appear in the bottom. Can u please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that's a UITableView inside?

If so, you shouldn't be animating it's frame you should use:

```
– scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

or:

```
– scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:
```